# Seleccionar elemento dentro de datatable con laravel dusk

Tags: laravel, datatables, test, html-select

Para poder completar mi test tengo que seleccionar una opcion de un select dentro de una tabla con datatable (https://datatables.net/) pero laravel dusk no encuentra el elemento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo trato de seleccionar la opcion del select de esta forma en el test:

```
$browser->with('#tabla_excel', function ($table) {
            $table->select('#select_0', '1');
        });
```

Asi se ve mi tabla, que tiene como id 'tabla_excel' y el select tiene asignado el id 'select_0':
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]